# MS Access 2007 : Count Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have created a database which will count the amount of procedures a person has completed and then a query will display the number of times they recieved a particular score for a particular procedure. These scores being "N" "B" and "C". I use the count function to work this out.

The procedures are selected from a table. Within the query would it be possible for me to output the procedure name [Adult Procedure] in the first column even if there is no data for that procedure.

Here is the query i have produced but it only outputs data for procedures that have data. I would like it to print all procedure names and if no data is contained to simply add zero to the column.

Here is a link to an image the results of the query
http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattcripps/6641851977/
I want the first column to include all procedures or which there are about 20.

```
TRANSFORM Count(tblEntryData.[Entry ID]) AS [CountOfEntry ID]
SELECT tblEntryData.[Adult Procedure], Count(tblEntryData.[Entry ID]) AS [Total Of Entry ID]
FROM tblEntryData
GROUP BY tblEntryData.[Adult Procedure]
PIVOT tblEntryData.Grade;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I must be missing something here. If no grades have been entered for a procedure, you should be seeing a 1 (or > 1) in the "Total Of Entries" column. Perhaps posting the "tblEntryData" data would help.

Comment: The query you wrote looks correct.

Comment: I remember a crosstable setting like "fixed columns", which may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the a table of possible [Adult Procedure] existed all you would need is a LEFT JOIN. This would be the recommended solution

```
TRANSFORM Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [CountOfEntry ID]
SELECT ap.[Adult Procedure], Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [Total Of Entry ID]
FROM tblAdultProcedure ap
     LEFT JOIN tblEntryData ed
     ON ap.[Adult Procedure ID]  = ed.[Adult Procedure ID]
GROUP BY ap.[Adult Procedure]
PIVOT ed.Grade;
```

However it is still possible to do it without using another table by deriving the table via another SQL statement (although it will be slower)

```
TRANSFORM Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [CountOfEntry ID]
SELECT ap.[Adult Procedure], Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [Total Of Entry ID]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Adult Procedure] FROM tblEntryData) ap
     LEFT JOIN tblEntryData ed
     ON ap.[Adult Procedure]  = ed.[Adult Procedure]
GROUP BY ap.[Adult Procedure]
PIVOT ed.Grade;
```

Note: you can also put `SELECT DISTINCT [Adult Procedure] FROM tblEntryData` into a query and then use as you would a table.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tired the suggested solution and am getting the following error
"Access database engine does not recognise 'tblEntryData.Grade' as a valid field name

Comment: @user1132612 I used an table alias and forgot to update the references. I've fixed it.

Comment: I have tried again and now am getting an error message saying that access does not recognize tblEntryData.[Entry ID]

Comment: @user1132612 doh I missed one on the Transform clause. Fixed again

Comment: thanks very much, After a bit of tinkering I have got it to work